# Is there a way of determine which compueters are lagging and not using javascript?  

Tags: javascript, css, transition

In my website I have developed a lot of CSS3 transitions. I have found that in old computers the transitions are lagging. The lagging lower the user experience of the website. Is there a way of determine which compueters are lagging and not using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way of determine which compueters are lagging and not using javascript?

Yes, both of these methods require some way to log your visitors and their capabilities on the server-side. An 'analytics' tools will probably tell you who has javascript and who does not (or you can manually check using tricks like a `<noscript><blah src="log-that-my-ip-doesnt-have-javascript"/></noscript>`).

Measuring responsiveness is a much more subjective matter. If you were up to the task, the "correct" way to do it would be to write a client-side responsiveness profiler in javascript, which sent back statistics. For example, perhaps a setInterval of 100ms that checks to see if the current time is more than 100ms since the last call (indicating UI lag).

Personally, I would not worry about it if it's a personal website.

The real question is, what would you do with such information? It might be unwieldy perhaps to support two different versions of the site, but such information would in fact you to disable "sexy" effects, and is a very interesting idea. I might use it myself; good luck!

Comment: Also the fact that they have old hardware may not matter much; I have seen modern browsers on fast hardware brought down to a crawl because they're repainting the entire page every frame (e.g. some webkit bugs).

Comment: It's probably worth your while reading the [mark-down editing page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how to format in-line code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking, but what do CSS3 transitions have to do with JavaScript? If you want to detect whether a browser supports CSS3 *using* JavaScript, have a look at the resource over here:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-detect-css-support-in-browsers-with-javascript/

Only the most modern browsers have good support for CSS3, so to those using powerful browsers on an old system, I'm not sure what you're going to do about that. Other than detecting operating system, there's really nothing you can do (easily) to determine how much taxing of system resources a browser is going to do by rendering transitions.

My personal preference would be to not have many transitions. Sure, they're "fancy" and "eye candy-ish," but I don't want to use a website that's making me wait to watch those fancy things happening. I think it detracts from the overall web browsing experience and you might lose visitors because of it. That's not to say that they can't be useful in some cases, just don't overdo it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to seriously consider browser support before using technology in web development.  Depends on whether you're okay or not with having your site break down for many people.  Consider CSS transitions support listed here:  http://www.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/browser-support-for-css3-and-html5_72/